# Why does numpy's transpose() combine datetimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

When I transpose a 2D array, it messes up the datetime. Is it because numpy can only handle numeric values, but not datetimes?

```py
from datetime import date, datetime
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import FieldType
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='MyName', password='Mypassword',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='mydatabase',
                              auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT `date` , `val_1`, `val_2`, `val_3` FROM mydatabase.MyTable LIMIT 3")
except Exception as ex:
    print("Error: %s" % str(ex))
    pass
data = []
try:
    data = cursor.fetchall()
except Exception as ex:
    print("Error: %s" % str(ex))
    pass
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
import numpy as np 
if data:
    print(data, "\n")
    data = np.array(data)      
    data = data.transpose()
    print(data)
```

This results from this outpust the following

```
[(datetime.date(2019, 3, 7), 1.478,1.568, 1.442),
(datetime.date(2019, 3, 8), 1.465, 1.549, 1.43), 
(datetime.date(2019, 3, 10), 1.46, 1.549, 1.423)] 

    [[datetime.date(2019, 3, 7) datetime.date(2019, 3, 8)
    datetime.date(2019, 3, 10)]
    [1.478 1.465 1.46]
    [1.568 1.549 1.549]
    [1.442 1.43 1.423]]
```

Comment: What makes you think the datetime data are corrupted?

Comment: it is not combined, just if you print numpy array, values are not separated by comma. Numpy is able to handle datetime also, check this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html . Transpose behaves as it should.

Comment: `data` starts as a list of lists.  `np.array(data)` makes a (3,4) shape object dtype array.  Transpose changes it to (4,3).  The first row contains the 3 dates.

Comment: Well, how about that. I thought it corrupted the array, but it actually worked just fine with the code above. I just got confused when the first elements of DateTime were on one row, and the last DateTime element on the following row. I was expecting them to be all on the same row. Well, thanks guys for correcting me.